# fstream file size in codepoints

Tags: c++, locale, fstream, codecvt

There are many questions on getting the file size of an std::fstream's file, but they all return the file size in bytes and are error prone if the file is open in another stream.

I want to know the file size in codepoints, not bytes.

Now `std::fstream::seekg(0,std::ios::end)` followed by `std::fstream::tellg()` only returns the length in bytes. This doesn't tell me how many UTF-16/32 characters are in the file. Divide the result by `sizeof(wchar_t)` I hear you say. Doesn't work for UTF-8 files and IS NOT portable.

Now, for the more technical minded, I have `imbued` the stream with my own `std::codecvt` class. `std::codecvt` has a member `length()` which, given two pointers into the stream calculates the length and returns either max or number of output characters. I would have thought that seeking on the file would seek by `codecvt::intern_type` rather than by the base `char` type.

I've looked into the `fstream` header and found that seek infact doesn't use the `codecvt`. And, on my version from VS2010, the `codecvt::length()` member is not even mentioned. Infact, on each call to `codecvt::in()`, a new string object is created and increased in size by 1 char each time `in()` returns `partial`. It doesn't instead call the `codecvt::max_length()` member and supply the call with an adequate buffer.

Is this just my implementation or can I expect others to do the same? Has `std::fstream` been rewritten for VS2012 to make full use of locales?

Basically, I'm fed up of having to write my own file handlers every time I use text files. I'm hoping to create an `fstream` derived class that will first read a files BOM, if present, and imbue the correct `codecvt`. Then convert those characters to `char`, `wchar_t` or whatever the code calls for. I'm also hoping to code it in such a way that if prior knowledge of the encoding is known, a `locale` can be specified on construction.

Would I be better off working directly on the internal buffer, in affect re-writing the fstream class or are there some tricks I'm unaware of?

Comment: It seems in general a bad idea to try to figure out the size of a utf8 encoded file in codepoints. You have to read the entire file for that. I would argue there should be no reason to know that size ahead of time. Also allocating a buffer to fit an entire file is also dangerous since files can be quite big and not fit. Read it piece by piece.

Comment: @madnut I agree that loading the whole file is not good hence my use of `codecvt`. The major problem is seeking within a file. These fstreams are not text file friendly. But I think you are wrong about knowing the length of a file before hand. In some instances it is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you expect that:

```
`std::basic_fstream<CharT,Traits>::seekg`
```

(which by inheritance is `basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::seekg`), ought to
perform the stream-positioning operation in units that are the
`intern_type` of whatever `codecvt` with which the stream is imbued.

Template `basic_istream` is declared:

```
template< 
    class CharT, 
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>
> class basic_istream;
```

In the declaration of the member function:

```
basic_istream & basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::seekg(pos_type pos)
```

`pos_type` is `std::char_traits<CharT>::pos_type` which therefore is
a type determined in any implementation solely by the `CharT` template 
argument of the `basic_istream` class and without reference to any `codecvt`.

A `basic_fstream<char>`, for instance remains a `basic_fstream<char>`,
and its `pos_type` remains `basic_fstream<char>::pos_type`,
regardless of the encoding that is chosen to read or write it.

The declarations above are respectively as per C++11 Standard § 27.7.1
and § 27.7.2.1. The fact that `pos_type` is invariant with
respect to any imbued `codecvt`, and hence also the behaviour of `seekg(pos_type)`,
are therefore consequences of the Standard.

Equivalent remarks apply for `basic_istream& seekg( off_type off, std::ios_base::seekdir dir)`.

The `std::codecvt::intern_type` is the type of the elements of the internal
sequence to which or from which the specified encoding will
translate an external sequence of elements of type `extern_type`. The
`intern_type` is the element type of the "in-program" sequence and
the `extern_type` is the type of "in-file" sequence. The `intern_type`
has got nothing to do with positioning operations on the file.

If you *must* find out the size of a file in codepoints, and presuming
that the possible encodings of interest are UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32, then
for the first two of these you have no choice but to read the entire file,
because they are variable-length encodings, with a UTF-8 codepoint consuming
1-4 bytes and a UTF-16 codepoint consuming 2 or 4 bytes. UTF-32 is a 
fixed-length 4-byte encoding, so in that case you might compute the number of 
complete codepoints as the byte-length of the file, minus BOM-length if any, 
divided by 4, if you discount the possibility of encoding errors except at end-of-file.

For the variable length encodings, the simplest way of counting
the codepoints will be with a template function parameterized by an
indicator of the presumed encoding. It will read the file, first
consuming the BOM, if any, in units of `char` or `char16_t` as appropriate,
identifying each unit that is the lead element of a codepoint in
the presumed encoding; verifying the presence of the number of subsequent
elements required by the lead element, and incrementing the codepoint count
if they are found.

Comment: I see what you mean with reference to the `pos_type`. I've currently been reading through the source code of these classes to see how it's working internally. And I'm surprised to see that the `basic_streambuf` employs no buffering. It calls into the 'c' file functions for each operation. Anyway, file size aside, I think I may have to write my own implementation simply because `basic_fstream` doesn't allow one to specify a new/replacement `basic_streambuf`.

Answer (score 0):

The `length` function of `std::char_traits` returns the number of `CharT`characters, which isn't necessarily the number of bytes. So basically what you would need to do is read the buffer of your file into an `std::string` and print its `size()`:

```
std::ofstream out("out.txt");
out.rdbuf()->pubimbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF8"));

std::streambuf* p = out.rdbuf();
p->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::beg);

std::string data; //  use std::u16string for UTF-16 data

data.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(out),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

std::cout << "We have " << data.size() << " codepoints";
```